# Git credentials when npm has a git dependency

Tags: git, jenkins, npm

I have a Jenkins job to build my JS application.

In my `package.json` I have a dependency that looks like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "my_private_package": "git+https://my-server/my-repo.git#1.0.0"
}
```

I use the [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) along with the [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) to clone the repo, then a shell script to run `npm install`.

When Jenkins runs `npm install`, `npm` errors out with `npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed`

Due to our self hosted git server and bureaucracy I'm unable to do anything with adding an oAuth token to the git url.

Is there a way for me to set my git credentials so that npm can install from my password protected git repo?

Comment: can you possibly add the public key on your jenkins slaves to the hosted git repo attached to a user that has access?

Answer (score 8):

You can vend HTTPS credentials to git using the [credential-helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) config with a file. The [file format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store#_storage_format) is just an HTTPS URL with the `user:password` credentials part filled in. Something like:

```sh
CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH="$HOME/.git/my-ci-credentials"
echo 'https://ci-user:ci-password@myRepoHost.example.com/' > "$CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH"
```

Because npm clones the repo outside the context of your project folder, you'll need to specify this config at the user, rather than project, level:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper "store --file=$CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH"
```

After this, npm should be able to clone the repo.

Comment: I found this helpful. Thanks for the answer. But there is a fix in this. It's not 
cat but echo.

Comment: @MuhammedKK thanks. i've updated the snippet to use `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the git+ssh way of installing the dependency, like `git+ssh://my-server/my-repo.git#1.0.0`

Then on the Jenkins `.ssh` folder add a `config` file with the content:

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<rsa file>
```

Then Jenkins knows to use that ssh key for any github.com url. You need to have a Jenkins git user or deploy key associated with the project you are trying to import.

Answer (score 0):

Very usefule info is that npm apparently also can use the GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable.
So you could specify an ssh credential like this:

`export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key'`